# CDN routing sometimes sends me to overseas IPs, intermittent

Tags: domain-name-system, cdn

I recently changed ISPs but also swapped out our hardware firewall.
Since then I have noticed intermittent CDN issues, seemingly only with Akamai. I got clued into this when numerous sites wouldn't load thanks to Geo-IP filtering.
Numerous sites for US based organizations that seem to use Akamai are being routed to web servers in Brazil, Spain, Norway, Germany, South Africa, Australia, etc.

We are using google's DNS servers. I notice that when I use ping or nslookup to query the IP, I get IPs that are geolocated outside the country. But from a test computer located at a different facility they're resolving to domestic IPs.

Example: when I do nslookup on [www.npr.org](http://www.npr.org) it shows that I'm using 8.8.8.8 for the server, and resolves every time to e103193.dsca.akamaiedge.net. From my workstation though, that ends up as 23.65.124.79 (India) or 2.20.178.115 (South Africa) or 2.16.197.41 (Brazil), while from a remote test station it resolves to the same akamaiedge FQDN, but points to 23.203.48.136, based in the US.

And here's more complication -- it's intermittent. It'll resolve to foreign IPs for awhile, and then suddenly start resolving to domestic IPs.

I have talked with my firewall vendor support, who are determined that it's not a firewall issue. I've reached out to my ISP as well but have not yet received a response.

Does this seem like an issue with my ISP? Any recommendations on troubleshooting steps that I should be doing to narrow this down?

Comment: "We are using google's DNS servers." I'd start by switching this up. CloudFlare, OpenDNS, your ISP's own resolver... at least as a debugging step.

Comment: I typically use my own ISP's DNS servers, but have the same result with them or google DNS. I included google DNS here in an attempt at simplifying.

Comment: Maybe your ISP (or an upstream provider) is interfering with the DNS - it's trivial to do with UDP and not very hard with TCP. Try using a DoH resolver with different providers.